# How to calculate my age

Tags: date-and-time

How to calculate my age given my date of birth ? I have read other questions and answers but it is not satsified with the answers. My question is how do I calculate my current age if my birthdate is 18.03.2000?

Comment: Is this about Wolfram Mathematica?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming the question is related to Mathematica, the code would be

```
DateDifference["18.03.2000", Now,  "Years"]
```

[image]

Note that DateDifference is good at interpreting various formats of date. E.g. "2000-01-03"

Comment: You can specify units down to whatever granularity that you want, e.g., `DateDifference["18.03.2000", Now, {"Years", "Months", "Days", "Hours",
   "Minutes", "Seconds"}]` or `DateDifference["18.03.2000", Now, {"Years", "Months", "Days"}]`